# What would be the perfect way from upload image data from excel sheet to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, vba, excel

I have excel sheet having text and image data,

ex. [image: Demo Image]

Now I need to insert whole `.xls data` as well image into mysql database,

I tried replaced image cell with image path and manually moved image on server, but its not feasible for large number of data.

Is there any better solution for this ???

any help appreciated

Comment: Where is your excel file from?

Comment: not getting you @Pemapmodder, .csv fiile basically need to upload from our local system

Comment: Sorry, but '... not feasible for large number of data...' means 'we procrastinated and kept using an app that is not suitable for the job and now we're stuck.'  Your approach is the correct one. In the US we have 'interns' who we would have do such a mundane, tedious task.

Comment: That's not a image from a csv file..... what format of Excel file is it, and what library are you using to read it?

Comment: @MarkBaker, .csv excel format, and reading this we are using jQuery csv library

Comment: Then how is the image included in the csv file? Is it a url? or a file reference? Is it base64 encoded? Because csv doesn't naturally support images in the way native Excel formats do

Comment: @MarkBaker, I have just inserted image but we are not able to get its original value, its there any another way apart from `.csv extension`

Comment: What is your original file? Is it a csv or is it a native format (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML) Excel file.... even that is still unclear from your question.... How is the image data currently represented in that file? Until your question provides some real details, then you won't get any real answers